# How to Print the Errors on Console?

Tags: php, json

```
function loginuser() {
    $results=array();
    $errors = array();

        $username = 'abc';
        $password = '123';
if ($username='') {
            array_push($errors, "Username is required");
        }
        else if ($password='') {
            array_push($errors, "Password is required");
        }


            $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='$username' AND user_pass='$password'";
            $result = selection($query);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $results[] = row_jsonify($row);
    }










return json_encode($results);
return json_encode($errors);
}
```

Below is the code m printing but its throwing a sql error on console if i dont give a username or password i.e if i leave it empty like $username='  ';

what should i do here to print the errors on console as i dont have front end right now if the username or password is incorrect or empty

Comment: Just print it on the screen with print_r or var_dump ?

Comment: can you please guide me how?

Comment: Not more complicated than `print_r($myVariable)` and it is displayed (http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)

Comment: You have error on this line `if ($username='')`

Comment: try == for comparison

Comment: or === for more comparison

Comment: You should be hashing passwords

Comment: you are asking to print PHP errors in browser console which is not possible, php is server side language, to check if username and password fields are empty you have to use javascript validations, which can show errors on browser before form submission, you can also print error in console.

In javascript to print console type console.log("message");
In php we use print_r($array); var_dump($variable);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
showErrsInConsole(['err1', 'error2', 'error3']);

function showErrsInConsole(array $errors)
{
    array_walk($errors, function (&$err) {
        $err = 'echo ' . $err;
    });
    $errors = implode(';', $errors);
    $exec = "gnome-terminal -x bash -c '$errors; sleep 1; read -n 1 -p \"press any key to close\"';";
    `$exec`;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this error "**Warning**: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, check if $_POST is not empty and print errors in else case just for testing.

To check if input fields are empty apply JavaScript validations to avoid empty from submission.

```
if(!empty($_POST["login"])) {
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='" . $_POST["user_name"] . "' and password = '". $_POST["password"]."'");
    $row  = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if(is_array($row)) {
    $_SESSION["user_id"] = $row['user_id'];
    } else {
    $message = "Invalid Username or Password!";
    }
}
```

Here is an example,to simplify your code, if you have any problem then try printing variables e.g. var_dump & print_r

```
<?php
session_start();
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","database_ex");

$message="";
if(!empty($_POST["login"])) {
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='" . $_POST["user_name"] . "' and password = '". $_POST["password"]."'");
    $row  = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if(is_array($row)) {
    $_SESSION["user_id"] = $row['user_id'];
    } else {
    $message = "Invalid Username or Password!";
    }
}else{
  //Print error message here if no username or password provided;
  echo "Invalid credentials"; 
  print_r($_POST);
  var_dump($_POST);
}
?>
```

Comment: _Try this_ answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.  Please do not condone/encourage unhashed password storage.  Warn.

Comment: If i Keep the username or passowrd as empty it gives me this error



"<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\StylersInquiry\Model\model_report.php</b> on line <b>24</b><br />"

Comment: Try this you will get to know how to write code for login functionality.
Here is an example https://phppot.com/php/php-login-script-with-session/

Comment: Can you explain where this code prints something to the console as requested by the OP?

Comment: To print something in php you have use print_r($variable) or var_dump($variable) it will print variable value on webpage not in console. In JavaScript you can print on browser console.

Comment: @MuhammadUsamaAhsan I have modified my answer, you can print you errors in else case.